# Spring injection for REST servlet - java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, spring, rest, nullpointerexception, code-injection

I am using Spring injection a REST servlet and it looks like something is going wrong with the injection. This is the error:

01/03/14 11:43:02:260 GMT] 0000001e ContainerResp E   The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container                                 java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: post stacktrace to question. also change your base-package to `base-package="com.ibm.mt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two problems, not sure which one affects you most.

1. You're missing an `ExceptionMapper` that should map exception types on your backend to HTTP responses.
2. You're getting a `NullPointerException`, regardless of the fact that the code runs within a REST container. Maybe if you look down to the stack trace of this `NullPointerException`, you can get a hint on what's going wrong.

Comment: The NullPinterException happens at this line:

String result = transactionBo.save();

It looks like transactionBo has not been correctly injected.

Comment: Indeed. It seems that class `TodosResource` is not Spring-managed, because in your `applicationContext.xml` you only scan package `com.ibm.mt.model`, while `TodosResource` is in package `com.ibm.mt.resources`. Additionally, you might need to annotate this class with a stereotype annotation from Spring, e.g. `@Component`, in order to make it Spring-managed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Component missing was the reason.